# How to pick key words from a list, after appending a .csv file to that list?

Tags: python, list, keyword

I need to be able to pick keywords from an Excel CSV file, I've appended the file to a list. The program is a Phone Troubleshoot, and I need the input ("The screen won't turn on") to have the same output as if I inputted ("The display is blank").

```
"Troubleshooting Program to give the user a solution to a trouble they've     encountered based on inputted key words."

phoneprob=input("What problem are you having with your phone? ")
prob=open("phone.csv","r")
phone=prob.read()
prob.close()
eachProb=phone.split("\n")

print(eachProb)
problist=[eachProb]

print (problist)
```

Comment: Please mention what you are expecting(input and output)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build a keyword dictionary or retriving a sentence problem ?
In both case, you need to associate a problem to keywords.

A basic approch to get keywords is to split the sentence in words (using s.split()) and update keyword list with the most used of them...
[difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) can help here.

Since we don't know the given file schema, i assume it's just a list of sentence and you provided keyword/problems elsewhere (situation Dict).

For example:

```
csv_ret = ["I can't turn on my phone", "The screen won't turn on", "phone The display is blank"]

situations = {
    "screen": ["turn on", "blank", "display", "screen"],
    "battery": ["turn on", "phone"]
}


def get_situation_from_sentence(sentence):
    occurences = {}
    for word in sentence.split():
        for key, value in situations.items():
            if word in value:
                if occurences.get(key) is None:
                    occurences[key] = [word]
                elif word not in occurences.get(key):
                    occurences[key].append(word)
    averages = {k: ((len(v) * 100) / len(situations[k])) for k, v in occurences.items()}
    return "{}, {}".format(averages, sentence)

for sentence in csv_ret:
    print(get_situation_from_sentence(sentence))
```

results:

> {'battery': 50.0}, I can't turn on my phone
>
> {'screen': 25.0}, The screen won't turn on
>
> {'screen': 50.0, 'battery': 50.0}, phone The display is blank

This code evaluate a sentence problems and related keyword match in percent.

Once again this is a very basic solution, and you probably need something more robust (lexer/parser, machine learning ...) but sometime simpler is better :)